# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" after babel compilation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using this docs https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#run-jsx-preprocessor to add a React component with JSX to my website.
I run this command to compile:

`npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod`

And I get this error in chrome console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Which comes from this line in the compiled file:
`import _regeneratorRuntime from 'babel-runtime/regenerator';`

I don't get it- in the docs they state that you can use babel just like a CSS preprocessor, but here it seems that `_regeneratorRuntime` depends on the `node_module` folder, but i'm not planing to run `npm i` in production, it is only to compile my JSX to a .js file which should be a standalone file any browser can run.

In package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

In HTML footer:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/react-components/index.js"></script> <!-- index.js compiled from src/index.js -->
```

Comment: What does your `babelrc` file look like?

Comment: I didn't create any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a babelrc file in your project or simply run this command `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`
Also add this code: `{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}`

Comment: Updated my pakcage.json file with these devDependencis: `"@babel/core": "^7.9.6", "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4", "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4"` and change the command to `npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets @babel/preset-react` and now it works. thanks!