# Why does <> give SyntaxError: Unexpected token in my React .js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is avery simple React jsx to js convertor project we're using to integrate React code into a legacy .aspx website. Eventually the who website will be written in React.

Whenever the Fragment shorthand <> is used the compiler returns a SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

Sample.js

```
import React from "react";

function Sample() {
    return (
        <>
            Hello world
        </>
    );
}
```

```
SyntaxError: src/Sample.js: Unexpected token (6:9)
  4 | function Sample() {
  5 |     return (
> 6 |         <>
    |          ^
  7 |             Hello world
  8 |         </>
  9 |     );
```

The project is using Babel 7.17.7 and babel-preset-react-app 3.1.2 which I think means the presets are set to recognize the shorthand <>.

This is the contents of the package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "jsx.bat"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Russ Petersen (http://www.petesoft.com/)",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

I'm invoking the compile process with this command line.

jsx.bat

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod
```

Yes we can use <React.Fragment> but <> has more style.

Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: You don't have react in your dependencies?

Comment: Thanks, YTGS, right you are. I added it, but have the same results.

Comment: I don't see it in your code above but did you forget to import React? -- `import React from 'react'`. You can delete the `const {} = React` because it does not really do anything useful

Comment: Are you processing .js files as JSX?

Comment: @slebetman, I removed the `const {} = React;` and added `import React from "react";` but nothing changed.

Comment: @VLAZ yes I've tried the original file as both .jsx and .js with the same results.

Comment: Are you trying to create a React build pipeline from scratch? Any reason you can't use create-react-app?

Comment: Can you show what command you are running to compile the jsx? How are you running Babel?

Comment: @slebetman I'm not building a full React application yet, that will come later. Right now I'm embedding individual .js files (created from a React .js or .jsx file) into a legacy .aspx file. So a create-react-app doesn't directly help yet.

Comment: @slebetman good point about how it is being invoked, I added the jsx.bat command line to the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" after babel compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003127/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-after-babel)

Changed command line (jsx.bat) to

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets @babel/preset-react
```

and

package.json devDependencies to

```
"devDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7"
  }
```